# How can I change the baseline value for the negative serial chart?

Tags: amcharts

http://www.amcharts.com/demos/date-based-line-chart/

So I basically have this working. I would like to change the baseline of this graph (0) so that it starts with 22.21 instead. Anything below 22.21 goes into the negative area of the chart, and anything above goes into the positive area of the chart.

I can't seem to find out how to change that baseline, or starting index, or base Axis in the documentation.

The context is this:

I have a suggested price (22.21) - if the price for the item is above 22.21, then it should be in the positive range. If it's lower than 22.21, then it should be in the negative range.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: are you looking for baseline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add:  "negativeBase":22.21 to graphs config.

Comment: This seems to be half of the solution, but the zero isn't updating to be 22.21 either.

Comment: Value axis has a property baseValue, you could set it to 22.21, although I am not sure if that's what you want to achieve.

Comment: I think it's just darker because zero is quite literally the baseline for the entire graph. This will work for what I need. Thank you for your answer. Once I've had a chance to experiment with higher values, I'll post my results here.